# How can I generate similar sets of fields in views quickly from within the views ui?

Tags: 7, views

I have several views that I have made of the users on my site.  Each view has different contextual filters, pages, and fields.  However, certain "groups" of fields are the same.

In particular, I have a series of four checkboxes on the user profile that I use the views module's rewriting ability to display, and this "group" of four fields is the same among all views.

Is there a way to somehow save this as a reusable unit within the views UI so I don't have to input it manually all the time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing to do it to add all of the common fields to the Master display, and then a few displays to the view that get customized for the individual uses using overrides.

Comment: I was hoping there would be some concept like "field sets" which I didn't know about, but I suppose no luck...